# Sub query using django mongoengine

Tags: django, database, mongodb, mongoengine

is there a way to combine the following 2 queries in a single query using django-mongoengine library?

```
Table2 schema = {'_id': int, 'list': Array of int}
Table1 schema = {'_id': int, ....}
```

```
id_list = Table2.objects.get(id=375).list
filtered = Table1.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
```

thanks

Comment: This is exactly what [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation) is for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for [uncorrelated subquery](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#uncorrelated-subquery)

```
pipeline = [
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "Table2",
        "pipeline": [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "_id": 375
                },
            },
        ],
        "as": "any"
    },
},
{
    "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
                {
                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$any", 0]
                },
                "$$ROOT"
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "any": 0,
    }
},
{
    "$match": {
        "$expr": {
            "$in": ["$_id", "$list"]
        }

    },
}
]
data = Table1.objects().aggregate(pipeline)
```